# How to assert the page after press a button which does a slow ajax call, with zombiejs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, zombie.js

I'm using zombiejs to test a html page, which has a button, when clicks on it, it will issue an ajax call, and update the page after several seconds.

**/static/ajax-button.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        function fetchResponse() {
            $.get('/delay/8', function(data) {
                $('#response').text(data);
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="mybutton" onclick="fetchResponse()">Click me to fetch response</button>
<div id="response">please wait for a while ...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app/app.js**

using expressjs:

```
app.get('/delay/:seconds', function(req, res) {
    const seconds = req.param("seconds") || 1;
    setTimeout(function() {
        res.send('Delayed Hello World in ' + seconds + 's!')
    }, seconds * 1000);
});
```

**test/press-button-spec.js**

```
const Browser = require('zombie');
const moment = require('moment');
const expect = require('expectations');

// We're going to make requests to http://example.com/???
// Which will be routed to our test server localhost:3000
Browser.localhost('example.com', 3000);

describe('browser.pressButton', function() {

    const browser = new Browser();

    this.timeout(10000);

    before(function(done) {
        console.log("######## browser.visit");
        browser.visit('/static/ajax-button.html', done);
    });

    before(function(done) {
        console.log("######## browser.pressButton");
        browser.pressButton('#mybutton', done);
    });

    it('should find "Delayed Hello World!" in page after a while', function(done) {
        console.log("######## testing");
        console.log(browser.html());
        browser.assert.status(200);
        browser.assert.text('#response', "Delayed Hello World in 8s!");
    });

});
```

But when I use mocha to run it as:

```
mocha test/press-button-spec.js
```

It reports:

```
➜  zombiejs-test git:(master) ✗ mocha test/press-button-spec.js


  browser.pressButton
######## browser.visit
######## browser.pressButton
    1) "before all" hook


  0 passing (5s)
  1 failing

  1) browser.pressButton "before all" hook:
     Timeout: did not get to load all resources on this page
```

Seems `browser.pressButton('#mybutton', done);` is timeout, because the default wait time for zombiejs is `5000ms`, but the ajax call need `8s` to finish.

How to fix it?

---

You can also find the code from this https://github.com/freewind/zombiejs-test

After you cloned it, run:

```
node app/app.js
mocha test/press-button-spec.js
```

---

UPDATE:

I can add `browser.waitDuration = '10s'` to set a global wait duration, to make the test pass, but I'm not sure if it's the best way.

Answer (score 1):

We can call `browser.pressButton` without passing callback, and then check them in `browser.wait`:

```
it('should find "Delayed Hello World!" in page after a while', function(done) {
    browser.pressButton('#mybutton');
    browser.wait(10000).then(function() {
        browser.assert.status(200);
        browser.assert.text('#response', "Delayed Hello World in 8s!");
    }).then(done, done)
});
```

https://github.com/freewind/zombiejs-test/blob/master/test/wait-spec.js#L28